# php - can't connect to mysql using different method

Tags: php, mysql

```
host = ***.**.**.**
username = ****
password = ****
db name = test1
port = 3307
```

I can connect to my MySQL database using this php

```
<?php
$servername = "***.**.*.**";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "test1";
$dbport = "3307";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $dbport);
?>
```

but I can't connect using this

```
<?php
define ("DB_ACCESS", "mysqli");
define ("DB_HOST", "***.**.*.**");
define ("DB_NAME", "test1");
define ("DB_USER", "****");
define ("DB_PASSWORD", "****");
define ("DB_PORT", "3307");

global $dbdtk_dbaccess, $dbdtk_dbhost, $dbdtk_dbuser, $dbdtk_dbpasswd,
$dbdtk_dbname, $dbdtk_dbport;

$dbdtk_dbaccess     = DB_ACCESS;
$dbdtk_dbhost   = DB_HOST;
$dbdtk_dbuser   = DB_USER;
$dbdtk_dbpasswd = DB_PASSWORD;
$dbdtk_dbname   = DB_NAME;
$dbdtk_dbport   = DB_PORT;

$db = &ADONewConnection($dbdtk_dbaccess);
$db->debug = 0;
$db->Connect($dbdtk_dbhost, $dbdtk_dbuser, $dbdtk_dbpasswd,
$dbdtk_dbname, dbdtk_dbport);
$ADODB_FETCH_MODE = ADODB_FETCH_BOTH;
?>
```

what's wrong with my code? I have to use both for my app. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: are there any errors?

Comment: never show your credential.

Comment: ok. But now it's just an example. Using default account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out by adding

```
$db->port = 3307;
```

so it become

```
<?php
define ("DB_ACCESS", "mysqli");
define ("DB_HOST", "***.**.*.**");
define ("DB_NAME", "test1");
define ("DB_USER", "****");
define ("DB_PASSWORD", "****");

global $dbdtk_dbaccess, $dbdtk_dbhost, $dbdtk_dbuser, $dbdtk_dbpasswd,
$dbdtk_dbname;

$dbdtk_dbaccess = DB_ACCESS;
$dbdtk_dbhost   = DB_HOST;
$dbdtk_dbuser   = DB_USER;
$dbdtk_dbpasswd = DB_PASSWORD;
$dbdtk_dbname   = DB_NAME;

$db = &ADONewConnection($dbdtk_dbaccess);
$db->port = 3307;
$db->debug = 0;
$db->Connect($dbdtk_dbhost, $dbdtk_dbuser, $dbdtk_dbpasswd,
$dbdtk_dbname);
$ADODB_FETCH_MODE = ADODB_FETCH_BOTH;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Default port for MySQL is `3306` not `3307` so check that too. and make sure you have include `adodb.inc.php`. In your code you didn't add this file

```
<?php

     include('adodb/adodb.inc.php');

     $db = ADONewConnection($dbdriver); # eg 'mysql' or 'postgres'

     $db->debug = true;

     $db->Connect($server, $user, $password, $database);

     $rs = $db->Execute('select * from some_small_table');

     print "<pre>";

     print_r($rs->GetRows());

     print "</pre>";

?>
```

this code example is from http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm here.

Comment: I have to use 3307 as port. Not using default for the port.